# How to install packages on distributions that dont have apt

Tags: linux, debian, unix, apt-get

i am searching the web for half a day now and found nothing so far.

I need a way to obtain any apt-get package as .deb file or something so i can install it without `apt-get install`.

For example i want to unzip a zip archive:

```
sh-4.3# unzip 2.zip
sh: unzip: command not found
sh-4.3# apt-get install unzip
sh: apt-get: command not found
```

Or a alternative i would also love would be just downloading apt from somewhere (?) and install it as .deb file.

Comment: Are you using Debian, Ubuntu or any other Debian-derived distribution?

Comment: @jcbermu `Linux CCTV 4.4.37-v7 #1 SMP Sat Dec 10 16:50:52 EET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux` to be exact: motionEyeOS on a RaspberryPi3B

Comment: if it is not a debian derivate you cannot use .deb files at all. Even worse if it is not any common distrubution using a package manager (fedora/centos, opensuse, arch, ...) you have to compile the program yourself

Comment: @user45891 it doesn't have MAKE tho :(

Comment: motionEyeOs is build via BuildRoot, which promises to make cross compiling easier. So you could compile on your PC and then transfer and install it

Comment: @user45891 which os would i need on my pc?

Comment: The official motionEye installation instructions recommend using the **latest version** of Raspbian OS on your Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

Comment: Official Raspbian website: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ Official motionEye website: https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneye/wiki/Install-On-Raspbian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install packages in motionEyeOS. In order to install software including motionEye on a Raspberry Pi, you can install Raspbian and then install motionEye in Raspbian by following the official motionEye installation instructions in [Install On Raspbian](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneye/wiki/Install-On-Raspbian). The instructions for installing motionEye from this link are duplicated below.

Show what version of Debian (also works for many Debian-based distributions like Raspbian) you are running using this command:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Example output of `cat /etc/issue` for Raspbian:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l
```

This output shows that a Raspbian distribution which is based on Debian Jessie (the latest version) is installed. In order to install motionEye, Raspbian also has to be an up-to-date version.

### Instructions

1. ffmpeg is missing from the official Debian repos. Moreover, the variant offered by deb-multimedia.org no longer works with Raspbian after recent updates. You can either compile it yourself (not recommended) or download this prebuilt package and install it:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneye/wiki/precompiled/ffmpeg_3.1.1-1_armhf.deb  
   sudo dpkg -i ffmpeg_3.1.1-1_armhf.deb
   ```

   Note: If you have previously added the deb-multimedia repo to your system and installed their version of ffmpeg, you'll need to remove the repo from your apt sources and run the following commands to remove related libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove libavcodec-extra-56 libavformat56 libavresample2 libavutil54
   ```
2. Install the dependencies from the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev curl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libx264-142 libavcodec56 libavformat56 libmysqlclient18 libswscale3 libpq5
   ```

   Note: v4l-utils appears to be preinstalled on Raspbian systems; if it isn't, please install it
3. Install motion:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/releases/download/release-4.0.1/pi_jessie_motion_4.0.1-1_armhf.deb  
   sudo dpkg -i pi_jessie_motion_4.0.1-1_armhf.deb
   ```

   Note: All official precompiled binaries of motion can be found here.
4. Install motioneye, which will automatically pull Python dependencies (tornado, jinja2, pillow and pycurl):

   ```
   sudo python -m pip install motioneye
   ```
5. Prepare the configuration directory:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/motioneye  
   sudo cp /usr/local/share/motioneye/extra/motioneye.conf.sample /etc/motioneye/motioneye.conf
   ```
6. Prepare the media directory:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/motioneye
   ```
7. Add an init script, configure it to run at startup and start the motionEye server:

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/local/share/motioneye/extra/motioneye.systemd-unit-local /etc/systemd/system/motioneye.service    
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload  
   sudo systemctl enable motioneye  
   sudo systemctl start motioneye
   ```
8. To upgrade to the newest version of motionEye, just issue:

   ```
   sudo python -m pip install motioneye --upgrade  
   sudo systemctl restart motioneye
   ```

Comment: `Linux CCTV 4.4.37-v7 #1 SMP Sat Dec 10 16:50:52 EET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux` lets see :D

Comment: Doesn't look like there's too much in here tho :( https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/search?p=1&q=apt&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Found this http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4~beta1_armhf.deb but `sh-4.3# dpkg -i apt_1.4~beta1_armhf.deb
sh: dpkg: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `motionEyeOS`. It is a very customized Linux distribution that it is exclusively dedicated to video surveillance.

The creator(s) of this distribution used [BuildRoot](https://buildroot.org/). It means that it's not a Debian distribution. Only Debian and distributions based on it as Ubuntu, Mint, etc use `apt-get`.

The developers have stated clearly on the [wiki](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki/FAQ#i-cant-seem-to-find-apt-get-or-any-other-package-manager-what-gives):

*"motionEyeOS is not a general-purpose Linux distribution. You **can't install packages** like you do with a normal distro. If you need to further customize your setup, installing motionEye on a common distro is recommended."*

Comment: I dont want to bloat the whole pi with packages. I just want to have some way to monitor my server load. (Like webmin or htop)

Answer (score -1):

You can download the source of a package using `apt-get source <package name>` and compile the code using the `make` command.

Comment: There is no apt at all on the system `sh: apt-get: command not found`